# Como remover o último espaço em cada linha de um textarea?

Tags: javascript, regex

Utilizo a função abaixo para substituir todos os caracteres diferentes de números em um textarea por "espaços". O problema é que no final de cada linha do textarea sempre tem um espaço. Como excluir esse último espaço e mantes os demais?

```js
function formatatextarea(tarea) { //formata as matrizes colocando espaco entre as dezenas
 var tab = RegExp("\\t", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(tab, ' ');

 /*var espaco = RegExp(" ", "g");
 tarea.value =
 tarea.value.replace(espaco,' ');*/

 var traco = RegExp("-", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(traco, ' ');

 var virg = RegExp(",", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(virg, ' ');

 var tespaco = RegExp("   ", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(tespaco, ' ');

 var ptvirg = RegExp(";", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(ptvirg, ' ');

 var pt = RegExp(/\./, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(pt, ' ');

 /*var pesp = RegExp(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
 tarea.value.replace(pesp," ");
 */
 var nl = RegExp(/(\r\n\s\r\n|\n\s\n|\r\s\r)/gm, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(nl, "\r\n");

 var nld = RegExp(/^\S.*$(\r\n\s|\n\s|\r\s)/gm, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(nld, "\r\n");

 var last = RegExp(/\s*,\s*$/, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(last, "\r\n");
  
 var special = RegExp(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(special, " ");

 var letter = RegExp(/[a-zA-Z]/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(letter, "");
 /*var tdespaco = RegExp(/\s+/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
 tarea.value.replace(tdespaco,'\r\n');*/

 if ($('#cjtsdezenas').val()[0] === " ") {
  $('#cjtsdezenas').val()[0] == "";
 }
 if ($('#cjtsdezenas').val()[1] === " ") {
  $('#cjtsdezenas').val()[1] == "";
 }
 var despaco = RegExp("  ", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(despaco, ' ');

}
```

---

Exemplo:

Cole a matriz abaixo no textarea para teste:

```
01-02-05-06-08-14-15
01-02-07-08-10-11-14
01-02-07-09-10-13-15
01-03-04-11-12-15-16
01-05-06-07-08-14-15
02-03-04-07-11-12-16
05-06-08-09-10-13-14
```

```js
function formatatextarea(tarea) { //formata as matrizes colocando espaco entre as dezenas



 var tab = RegExp("\\t", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(tab, ' ');

 /*var espaco = RegExp(" ", "g");
 tarea.value =
 tarea.value.replace(espaco,' ');*/

 var traco = RegExp("-", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(traco, ' ');

 var virg = RegExp(",", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(virg, ' ');



 var tespaco = RegExp("   ", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(tespaco, ' ');

 var ptvirg = RegExp(";", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(ptvirg, ' ');

 var pt = RegExp(/\./, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(pt, ' ');

 /*var pesp = RegExp(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
 tarea.value.replace(pesp," ");
 */
 var nl = RegExp(/(\r\n\s\r\n|\n\s\n|\r\s\r)/gm, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(nl, "\r\n");

 var nld = RegExp(/^\S.*$(\r\n\s|\n\s|\r\s)/gm, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(nld, "\r\n");

 var last = RegExp(/\s*,\s*$/, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(last, "\r\n");
  
 var special = RegExp(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(special, " ");

 var letter = RegExp(/[a-zA-Z]/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(letter, "");
 /*var tdespaco = RegExp(/\s+/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
 tarea.value.replace(tdespaco,'\r\n');*/

 if ($('#cjtsdezenas').val()[0] === " ") {
  $('#cjtsdezenas').val()[0] == "";
 }
 if ($('#cjtsdezenas').val()[1] === " ") {
  $('#cjtsdezenas').val()[1] == "";
 }
 var despaco = RegExp("  ", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(despaco, ' ');

}
```

```html
<textarea name="cjtsdezenas" id="cjtsdezenas" onchange="formatatextarea(this)"  cols="150" rows="10" placeholder="Cole uma sequência de X Dezenas em cada linha, separadas por 1 espaço ou selecione as dezenas utilizando o seletor acima."></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function formataTextarea() {

  var lines = document.getElementById('text-area').value.split('\n');
  var formated = [];
  
  // Percorre todas as linhas
  lines.forEach(line => {
    // Remove o ultimo caracter da linha se for espaço
    if (line.charAt(line.length - 1) === ' ') {
      line = line.substring(0, line.length - 1);
    }
    // Substitui todos os caracteres não numeros por espaço
    formated.push(line.replace(/\D/g, ' '));
  });

  // Escreve na textarea
  document.getElementById('text-area').value = formated.join('\n');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text-area" rows="6" cols="50">
Lorem ipsum d24olor sit, 
amet consectetur adi564pisicing elit. 9
Quasi corrupti re678pellendus 1 
deserunt fugi46at! 
Odio, nesciunt 678eveniet. 
 
</textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="formataTextarea();">FORMAT</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer trocar "tudo que não é número" por espaço, mas preservando as quebras de linha, é mais simples fazer assim:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    let textarea = document.getElementById('texto');
    textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/[^\d\n\r]/g, ' ');
});
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="texto" name="texto" rows="10" cols="30">
01-02-05-06-08-14-15
01-02-07-08-10-11-14
01-02-07-09-10-13-15
01-03-04-11-12-15-16
01-05-06-07-08-14-15
02-03-04-07-11-12-16
05-06-08-09-10-13-14</textarea>
</form>
```

No caso, a regex é `[^\d\n\r]`. O `[^` cria uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), que pega tudo que **não** for o que está nos colchetes.

No caso, dentro dos colchetes temos `\d` (um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) para dígitos de 0 a 9), além de `\r` e `\n` (caracteres usados como quebras de linha - o `\r`, no caso, é para as quebras de linhas do Windows, caso você copie e cole o texto de algum editor, por exemplo).

Ou seja, a regex substitui qualquer coisa que não for número ou quebras de linha. Desta forma o resultado da substituição não fica com os espaços no final (além de preservar as linhas originais).

---

[Nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397882/como-remover-o-%C3%BAltimo-espa%C3%A7o-em-cada-linha-de-um-textarea/397897?noredirect=1#comment781694_397897) você disse que também quer eliminar dois ou mais espaços. Neste caso, basta adicionar outro `replace`:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    let textarea = document.getElementById('texto');
    textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/[^\d\n\r]/g, ' ').replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');
});
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="texto" name="texto" rows="10" cols="30">
01-02    05-06-08-14-15
01-02-07      08-10-11-14
01-02-07-09-10  13-15
01-03-04-11-12-15-16
01-05-06-07-08-14-15
02-03-04-07-11-12-16
05-06-08-09-10-13-14</textarea>
</form>
```

Eu adicionei `replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ')` - repare que há um espaço antes do `{`. E no caso, o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{2,}` significa "dois ou mais". Ou seja, a regex substitui 2 ou mais espaços por apenas um.

Comment: Ótimo! E como faria para eliminar os espaços duplos por ventura gerados? Quero apenas um espaço entre os números.

Comment: @user2876585 Usando a matriz que vc colocou de exemplo, e o meu código, essa situação de ter mais que 2 espaços não ocorre, mas de qualquer forma atualizei a resposta com esse caso.

Answer (score 1):

Você já tentou usar o `.trim()`?  Ele remove todos os espaços iniciais e todos os finais da sentença.
Há também o `.trimRight()` ou o `.trimEnd()`, ambos retiram apenas os espaços ao final da sentença.
Isso não sobrescreve a variável, por tanto tem que atribuir o resultado a ela novamente.
Pelo que descreveu, isso te atende.

```js
var e = '   exemplo   ';

console.log('variavel: ' + e + '.')
console.log('trim: ' + e.trim() + '.');
console.log('trim end: ' + e.trimEnd() + '.');
console.log('trim right: ' + e.trimRight() + '.');
```

Comment: trimEnd() funcionou bem. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Cole a matriz abaixo no textarea para teste

```
01-02-05-06-08-14-15
01-02-07-08-10-11-14
01-02-07-09-10-13-15
01-03-04-11-12-15-16
01-05-06-07-08-14-15
02-03-04-07-11-12-16
05-06-08-09-10-13-14
```

```js
function formatatextarea(tarea) { //formata as matrizes colocando espaco entre as dezenas



 var tab = RegExp("\\t", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(tab, ' ');

 /*var espaco = RegExp(" ", "g");
 tarea.value =
 tarea.value.replace(espaco,' ');*/

 var traco = RegExp("-", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(traco, ' ');

 var virg = RegExp(",", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(virg, ' ');



 var tespaco = RegExp("   ", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(tespaco, ' ');

 var ptvirg = RegExp(";", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(ptvirg, ' ');

 var pt = RegExp(/\./, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(pt, ' ');

 /*var pesp = RegExp(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
 tarea.value.replace(pesp," ");
 */
 var nl = RegExp(/(\r\n\s\r\n|\n\s\n|\r\s\r)/gm, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(nl, "\r\n");

 var nld = RegExp(/^\S.*$(\r\n\s|\n\s|\r\s)/gm, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(nld, "\r\n");

 var last = RegExp(/\s*,\s*$/, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(last, "\r\n");
  
 var special = RegExp(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(special, " ");

 var letter = RegExp(/[a-zA-Z]/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(letter, "");
 /*var tdespaco = RegExp(/\s+/g, "g");
 tarea.value =
 tarea.value.replace(tdespaco,'\r\n');*/

 if ($('#cjtsdezenas').val()[0] === " ") {
  $('#cjtsdezenas').val()[0] == "";
 }
 if ($('#cjtsdezenas').val()[1] === " ") {
  $('#cjtsdezenas').val()[1] == "";
 }
 var despaco = RegExp("  ", "g");
 tarea.value =
  tarea.value.replace(despaco, ' ');

}
```

```html
<textarea name="cjtsdezenas" id="cjtsdezenas" onchange="formatatextarea(this)"  cols="150" rows="10" placeholder="Cole uma sequência de X Dezenas em cada linha, separadas por 1 espaço ou selecione as dezenas utilizando o seletor acima."></textarea>
```